# Vertx 3 : will Handler<RoutingContext> of an HTTP server be executed in the event/run loop or in a separate thred?

Tags: vert.x

Greeting;

I wonder if I created an vertx httpServer and added a handler class to handle the requests. Will the code inside the handler instance be executed in the same thread (event loop thread) or it will be executed asynchronously in a separate thread/thread pool and will not slow down the HTTPServer listening to new requests operation?

currently, I have a single Handler instance (a spring signelton bean that is implementing the Handler interface). when a lot of HTTP requests to the httpserver arrive, the handler code handles the requests slowly (requests are being executed after the requests are done for a long time but the vertx ThreadBlocked exception is not thrown)

Comment: vertx each vertical represents single thread. So to answer your question, single thread will be handling all requests.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Each server verticle is bound to an event loop thread. Each handler is bound to the same thread. It's quite easy to check:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    vertx.deployVerticle(new ServerVerticle());
}

public static class ServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.get("/").handler((r) -> {
            System.out.println("Handler " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            r.response().end("");
        });


        System.out.println("Main verticle " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8888);
    }
}
```

Access the server and you'll notice that your handler is on the same event loop thread as the server.

If you have slow working handlers, use EventBus and worker verticles:
http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#worker_verticles